# I want search to only return results that match all the tags (.match jQuery)

Tags: jquery, search, match

I am running a few jQuery functions to return search results on my website. Basically items are returned that match certain tags that I've given to objects. The problem I'm having is I only want items to be returned that match ALL the tags that I search for. Right now if I put multiple tags in the search box it will return results that match ANY of the tags. Is this possible?

Here's my code:

```
var $input = $('#myInput');
$input.on('keyup', search)

function myFunction(e) {
    // Declare variables
    var $q, $el, tags, match, tags;

    $q = e.target.value
    var $list = $container.children('li')

    if ($q.length < 2) {
        $list.hide();
        return;
    }

    console.log('list', $list)
    queryTags = $q.split(',').map(tag => tag.trim())
    console.log('tags', tags)

    $list.each(function(index, el) {            
        $el = $(el)
        tags = $el.attr('data-tags')

        for (var j = 0; j < queryTags.length; j++) {    
            match = tags.match(queryTags[j])            

            if (match) {
                $el.show();
                break;
            } else {
                $el.hide();
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the tags with `every` to check if all of them match. Also, when you're just checking to see whether a string contains another, you should use `.includes` - use `.match` when you're using a regular expression.

```
$list.each(function(index, el) {
    $el = $(el)
    if (queryTags.every(queryTag => tags.includes(queryTag))) $el.show();
    else $el.hide();
});
```

Comment: Just did that thank you. I have another issue if you want to take a crack at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139314/i-would-like-search-results-to-only-return-if-it-matches-the-whole-word-not-just